# Merge a dataframe with length one with another bigger

Tags: r

My first dataframe is:

df1 <- "C:/User"

And the second:

```
df2
 [1] "/Desktop"                                              
 [2] "/Desktop/all"                    
 [3] "/Programms"
```

I would like to merge them to a df like this:

```
"C:/User/Desktop"
"C:/User/Desktop/all"
"C:/User/Programms"
```

Comment: `df1` and `df2` are everything but data.frame.

Comment: Maybe even `merge(df1, df2)` would work

Comment: @RonakShah  No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Pascal it gives them as separate columns , maybe need to merge those columns as well to get what OP wants

Comment: @RonakShah  So complicated. `df1` and `df2` are character vectors, not data.frame.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, that is true. Answer from Richard is the simplest, i agree!

Comment: @RichardScriven Should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there are character vectors, not data frames.  You can simply use `paste0()`.

```
x1 <- "C:/User"
x2 <- c("/Desktop", "/Desktop/all", "/Programms")
paste0(x1, x2)
# [1] "C:/User/Desktop"     "C:/User/Desktop/all" "C:/User/Programms"
```